# New Windows 10 computer has desktop icons from old computer that don't work

Tags: windows, windows-10, sync, icons, desktop

I was trying to search for this, but I'm not finding any relevant results.

I bought a new laptop, because my old one was getting too slow. During setup I selected some option to sync activities between computers and to store my files in OneDrive. I'm not sure which option is the culprit here, but I'm guessing the latter.

Anyhow, when I logged in I had all my desktop icons from my old computer. The silly thing is that the apps that they open aren't even installed on this computer. Not yet anyway. So I have a desktop full of icons that don't work and I have two desktop icons for Microsoft Edge, even though I never use that browser.

Normally, I would just delete the duplicate icons, but since they are clearly synced from my old computer, I worry that they would get removed from there as well, and there they are actually useful. Perhaps it was silly of me to activate OneDrive. I don't really care about it, just thought it might be nice to have access to my files from any of the laptops.

Anyhow, what is the best way to deal with this? I'm not really a Windows user and on Mac I never have these silly problems. How can I have my two desktops independent and not have useless icons of apps that aren't even installed? If I delete an icon from my new laptop how can I make sure that it isn't also deleted from my old laptop? Going forward how do I make sure that icons of new apps don't show up on my old laptop as well? I just checked and the duplicate Microsoft Edge icon has appeared on the old laptop too.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off desktop synchronization in OneDrive.  If the extra icons still exist after doing so, you can delete them without worry they will affect the other machine.

Comment: The author should move the desktop out of the OneDrive directory.  If the author does not wish to do that, then they will want to also disable desktop synchronization, on both devices instead of just one.

Comment: Thanks, but some instructions on HOW to turn off desktop synchronization would be useful. I've already been searching the settings for something like that, without luck.

Answer (score 0):

So I kind of learned what not to do and from that I suppose you can deduct what to do.

On your old computer, you need to open explorer, right click on the desktop and select properties. Navigate to the `Location` tab and click `Restore Default`. This will allow you to move your desktop with all your files to a local directory instead of OneDrive. Just choose the appropriate options in the ensuing popups.

Unfortunately I did this on my new computer, so now I still have all the icons from my old computer on my new computer, but I lost all of them on my old computer. So basically the worst case scenario, the one I was trying to avoid by asking this question.

Anyhow, I hope this might help someone else not lose all their icons.